# How can I prevent the content editable div from inheriting styles from the copied content

Tags: frontend

when I copy content from another website and paste it on the content editable div the div takes the content styles that I have taken from another website. I wanna prevent it but how can I do it?

[check the image here I have paste the content from another website but it takes styles automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECY26.png)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Modal from "../Modal";

function CreatePostModal() {
  const [isPlaceholder, setIsPlaceholder] = useState(true);
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  const contentChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setIsPlaceholder("");
    setContent(e.target.innerHTML);
  };


  const blurHandler = () => {
    setIsPlaceholder(true);
  };

  // set placeholder on mount 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!content) {
      setIsPlaceholder(true);
    }
  }, [content]);

  return (
    <Modal>
<div className="relative">
<div
        contentEditable
        onInput={contentChangeHandler}
        onBlur={blurHandler}
        aria-label="What's on your mind?"
        suppressContentEditableWarning
        className="min-h-[60px] select-none"
      >
      </div>
      {isPlaceholder ? <p className="select-none   pointer-events-none  overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden absolute top-[2px] left-0  ">What&apos;s on your mind?</p> : ""}
</div> 
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default CreatePostModal;
```

Comment: I think the content you are copying is being pasted as HTML.  Paste it in a text editor to verify. You probably want to paste it as a plain string.

Comment: It's a react component.  The code hasn't any issues. I just wanna prevent the behavior of content editable auto styling.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.